# How to modifly SPARK_SUBMIT_OPTIONS using ansible

Tags: ansible

I need to modify the below line with some appended values using ansible.
This is the default value in /etc/zeppelin/conf/zeppelin-env.sh file.

```
export SPARK_SUBMIT_OPTIONS="$SPARK_SUBMIT_OPTIONS --conf 'spark.executorEnv.PYTHONPATH=/usr/lib/spark/python/lib/py4j-src.zip:/usr/lib/spark/python/:<CPS>{{PWD}}/pyspark.zip<CPS>{{PWD}}/py4j-src.zip' --conf spark.yarn.isPython=true"
```

I need to change it to something like below.

```
export SPARK_SUBMIT_OPTIONS="$SPARK_SUBMIT_OPTIONS --conf 'spark.executorEnv.PYTHONPATH=/usr/lib/spark/python/lib/py4j-src.zip:/usr/lib/spark/python/:<CPS>{{PWD}}/pyspark.zip<CPS>{{PWD}}/py4j-src.zip' --conf spark.yarn.isPython=true --jars /usr/local/mysql-connector-java-5.1.48.jar,/usr/local/spark-csv-1.5.0-s_2.10.jar,/usr/local/commons-csv-1.4.jar --driver-memory 2G"
```

I tried commenting out the default one and add new line like given below.

```
    - name: Comment out spark submit options
      replace:
        dest: /etc/zeppelin/conf/zeppelin-env.sh
        regexp: '^export SPARK_SUBMIT_OPTIONS='
        replace: '#export SPARK_SUBMIT_OPTIONS='
    - name: update spark submit options.
      lineinfile:
        path: /etc/zeppelin/conf/zeppelin-env.sh
        line: export SPARK_SUBMIT_OPTIONS="$SPARK_SUBMIT_OPTIONS --conf 'spark.executorEnv.PYTHONPATH=/usr/lib/spark/python/lib/py4j-src.zip:/usr/lib/spark/python/:<CPS>{{PWD}}/pyspark.zip<CPS>{{PWD}}/py4j-src.zip' --conf spark.yarn.isPython=true --jars /usr/local/flytxt/zeppelin/custom-lib/flytxtSparkLib/mysql-connector-java-5.1.48.jar,/usr/local/flytxt/zeppelin/custom-lib/flytxtSparkLib/spark-csv-1.5.0-s_2.10.jar,/usr/local/flytxt/zeppelin/custom-lib/flytxtSparkLib/commons-csv-1.4.jar --driver-memory 2G"
```

However when I am trying to modify the line using ansible.builtin.file module I am getting some error due to the value {{PWD}} present in it . Ansible detects that as a template variable and throws exception. Is there any option to resolve the issue using any of the ansible modules.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you need to work with {{mustashes}} in the text without 'help' from Jinja interpolation, you can use `!!unsafe` type.

```
- hosts: localhost
  tasks:
   - debug:
       msg: !!unsafe {{ inventory_hostname }}
```

It will print '{{ inventory_hostname }}'. Use !!unsafe for each argument to the lineinfile module to avoid interpolation.

More on that: https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_advanced_syntax.html#unsafe-or-raw-strings

Comment: Thanks!. Declaring an unsafe variable ```spark_pwd: !unsafe '{{PWD}}'``` and substituting the variable (```{{ spark_pwd }}```) in the line solved my issue.